# Why the laser line is just one, when should be 4 of them.why it's going from just PlayerShip and no from EnemyShip?

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, 2d

I make a game called Space Shooter. I added the lasers to both ships and put the Laser into LinkedList but when I run the game the laser is going on from one side of the player ship. Where are the other 3 lasers what should be on the sides. You can see what I mean in the photo below. I've already check the code twice but can't find what's wrong.

[image]

```
     class GameScreen implements Screen {
    
        //screen
        private Camera camera;
        private Viewport viewport;
    
        //graphics
        private SpriteBatch batch;
        private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
    
        private TextureRegion[] backgrounds;
        private float backgroundHeight; //height of background in World units
    
        private TextureRegion playerShipTextureRegion, playerShieldTextureRegion,
                enemyShipTextureRegion, enemyShieldTextureRegion,
                playerLaserTextureRegion, enemyLaserTextureRegion;
    
    
        //timing
        private float[] backgroundOffsets = {0, 0, 0, 0};
        private float backgroundMaxScrollingSpeed;
    
        //world parameters
        private final int WORLD_WIDTH = 72;
        private final int WORLD_HEIGHT = 128;
    
        //game objects
        private Ship playerShip;
        private Ship enemyShip;
        private LinkedList<Laser>PlayerLaserList;
        private LinkedList<Laser>EnemyLaserList;
    
    
    
        GameScreen() {
    
            camera = new OrthographicCamera();
            viewport = new StretchViewport(WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT, camera);
    
            //set up the texture atlas
            textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas("images.atlas");
    
            //setting up the background
            backgrounds = new TextureRegion[4];
            backgrounds[0] = textureAtlas.findRegion("Starscape00");
            backgrounds[1] = textureAtlas.findRegion("Starscape01");
            backgrounds[2] = textureAtlas.findRegion("Starscape02");
            backgrounds[3] = textureAtlas.findRegion("Starscape03");
    
            backgroundHeight = WORLD_HEIGHT * 2;
            backgroundMaxScrollingSpeed = (float) (WORLD_HEIGHT) / 4;
    
            //initialize texture regions
            playerShipTextureRegion = textureAtlas.findRegion("playerShip2_red");
            enemyShipTextureRegion = textureAtlas.findRegion("enemyBlack2");
            playerShieldTextureRegion = textureAtlas.findRegion("shield2");
            enemyShieldTextureRegion = textureAtlas.findRegion("shield1");
            enemyShieldTextureRegion.flip(false, true);
    
            playerLaserTextureRegion= textureAtlas.findRegion("laserGreen15");
            enemyLaserTextureRegion= textureAtlas.findRegion("laserRed03");
    
    
            //set up game objects
            playerShip = new PlayerShip(2, 3, 10, 10,
                    WORLD_WIDTH/2, WORLD_HEIGHT/4,2f,3,1,
                    0.05f, playerShipTextureRegion,playerShieldTextureRegion,playerLaserTextureRegion);
    
            enemyShip = new EnemyShip(2, 1, 10, 10,
                    WORLD_WIDTH/2, WORLD_HEIGHT*4/5,0.3f,3,1,0.8f
                    , enemyShipTextureRegion,enemyShieldTextureRegion,enemyLaserTextureRegion);
    
    
            PlayerLaserList = new LinkedList<>();
            EnemyLaserList = new LinkedList<>();
    
    
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void render(float deltaTime) {
            batch.begin();
    
    
            playerShip.update(deltaTime);
            enemyShip.update(deltaTime);
    
    
            //scrolling background
            renderBackground(deltaTime);
    
            //enemy ships
            enemyShip.draw(batch);
    
            //player ship
            playerShip.draw(batch);
    
    
    
            //lasers
    
            //create new Laser
            //player lasr
            if (playerShip.canFireLaser()) {
                Laser[] lasers = playerShip.fireLaser();
                for (Laser laser: lasers) {
                    PlayerLaserList.add(laser);
                }
            }
            //enemy lasers
            if (enemyShip.canFireLaser()) {
                Laser[] lasers = enemyShip.fireLaser();
                for (Laser laser: lasers) {
                    EnemyLaserList.add(laser);
                }
            }
            //draw the Lasers
            //remove old Laser
            ListIterator<Laser> iterator = PlayerLaserList.listIterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                Laser laser = iterator.next();
                laser.draw(batch);
                laser.yPosition += laser.movementSpeed*deltaTime;
                if (laser.yPosition > WORLD_HEIGHT) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
    
    
            //enemy lsaer list
            iterator = EnemyLaserList.listIterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                Laser laser = iterator.next();
                laser.draw(batch);
                laser.yPosition -= laser.movementSpeed*deltaTime;
    
                if(laser.yPosition + laser.height < 0)
                {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
    
    
    
            //explosions
    
            batch.end();
        }

package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

class EnemyShip extends Ship
{




        public EnemyShip(float movementSpeed, int shield, float width, float height, float xCentre, float yCentre,
                          float laserWidth, float laserHeight, float laserMovementSpeed, float timeBetweenShoots,
                          TextureRegion shipTexture, TextureRegion shieldTexture, TextureRegion laserTextureRegion) {
            super(movementSpeed, shield, width, height, xCentre, yCentre, laserWidth, laserHeight, laserMovementSpeed,
                    timeBetweenShoots, shipTexture, shieldTexture, laserTextureRegion);
        }

    @Override
    public Laser[] fireLaser() {
        Laser[] laser = new Laser[2];
        laser[0] = new Laser(xPosition + width * 0.18f, yPosition - laserHeight,
                laserWidth, laserHeight,
                laserMovementSpeed, laserTextureRegion);
        laser[1] = new Laser(xPosition + width * 0.82f, yPosition  - laserHeight,
                laserWidth, laserHeight,
                laserMovementSpeed, laserTextureRegion);

        timeSinceLastShoot = 0;

        return laser;
    }




    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch) {
        batch.draw(shipTexture, xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
        if (shield > 0) {
            batch.draw(shieldTexture, xPosition, yPosition-height*0.2f, width, height);
        }
    }
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class Laser
{
    float movementSpeed;

    //position and dimension
    float xPosition, yPosition;
    float width, height;


    //graphics
    TextureRegion textureRegion;

    public Laser(float movementSpeed, float xPosition, float yPosition, float width, float height, TextureRegion textureRegion) {
        this.movementSpeed = movementSpeed;
        this.xPosition = xPosition;
        this.yPosition = yPosition+33;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.textureRegion = textureRegion;
    }

    public void draw(Batch batch)
    {
        batch.draw(textureRegion,xPosition,yPosition,width,height);
    }
}package com.mygdx.game;


package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
class PlayerShip extends Ship {


    public PlayerShip(float movementSpeed, int shield, float width, float height, float xCentre, float yCentre,
                      float laserWidth, float laserHeight, float laserMovementSpeed, float timeBetweenShoots,
                      TextureRegion shipTexture, TextureRegion shieldTexture, TextureRegion laserTextureRegion) {
        super(movementSpeed, shield, width, height, xCentre, yCentre, laserWidth, laserHeight, laserMovementSpeed,
                timeBetweenShoots, shipTexture, shieldTexture, laserTextureRegion);
    }

    public Laser[] fireLaser()
    {
        Laser[] laser = new Laser[2];
        laser[0] = new Laser(xPosition + width * 0.07f, yPosition + height * 0.45f,
                laserHeight, laserWidth ,
                laserMovementSpeed, laserTextureRegion);
        laser[1] = new Laser(xPosition + width * 0.93f, yPosition + height * 0.45f,
                laserHeight, laserWidth,
                laserMovementSpeed, laserTextureRegion);

        timeSinceLastShoot = 0;





        return laser;




   }
}
```

Comment: Please inmclide a stacktrace and the line the exception is thrown from.

Comment: An easy way to diagnose this (you'll find similar problems every day as you continue, which is normal) is by adding print statements to the x and y coordinates to see if they're as you expect. Alternatively, run the code in debug mode and use breakpoints to see where the x and y values are being processed and why they don't match what you expect. Specifically for this problem, check to see if your x and y coordinates aren't being mixed up accidentally, if the screenshot is showing two lasers on top of each other.

Comment: It's not very likely anyone will be willing to debug that much code for you. I recommend you read up some on how to do basic debugging yourself. You can pause code execution and inspect if variables have the values you expect as the person above commented.